# Table View to DetailedView Problem

Tags: iphone, uitabbarcontroller, uitableview

I'm having a strange problem with a view in iOS on iPhone.

My App has a table and a tabBar. I can drill down just fine until I get to a DetailView, which gives details of a book (Name, author, ISBN and an Image)

This loads fine. However on that same DetailView I have a button that launches another view. This view displays fine, and on this view one can contact the Author (A text field and a submit button)

Here is where the problem starts

1) If I go to the detailed view and press the Contact Button three times i.e. (Open ContactView, Dimiss View, Open ContactView, Dismiss View) on the third press the App crashes

2) If I launch the ContactView and then dimiss it. If I drill back to the very top level and press the same book again, the App crashes i.e.

Harry Potter 1 > Detail View > Press Contact Button > Launch ContactView > Dimiss Contact View > Drill Back up to Top Level > Press Harry Potter 1

The App crashes at this point.

However if I do the same again:

Harry Potter 1 > Detail View > Press Contact Button > Launch ContactView > Dimiss Contact View > Drill Back up to Top Level > Press Harry Potter 2

The App doesn't crash.

Data Structure:

I used JSON as per this: (http://tempered.mobi/%20) to build my table.

Launching the DetailedView entails sending the view data about the selected book i.e. Selected row sends a Dictionary to the Detailed View containing all the info. The detailed view then launches.

I can't get any debug info but I have two theories:

1) I amn't managing memory right, which I have tripled checked.

2) Somewhere along the line I'm losing information about the selected book. The info is being sent to DetailedView but being lost once sent.

Any troubleshoot ideas gladly welcomed!

Answer (score 0):

Do a build and debug with the debugger window open. When the app crashes it will show you what method was last run. This should help you.

Another thing I might suggest is rewriting the affected code. Hopefully it's not to much. I'm not sure how long/good developer you are but I found that when I wrote an app while learning the code u first rewritten was awful and it caused problems later on which rewriting fixed.

Comment: Thank you for the reply Jonathan. I've been running with the Debugger and it doesn't give me any error output. From NSLog data is seems the ModalView launches the third time, then the App crashes.

I think I left it out but the "Contact Author" view is a modal view.

Comment: Place a breakpoint. Where ghoul think it's crashing. And then debug when the breakpoint is reached press continue and the debugger window should fil when it crashes.